# Paypal Future Payment

Tags: php, ruby, paypal, payment-gateway

I need to use **future payment** from web NOT using mobile SDK

Our users will pay us for renting some electronic devices monthly.

User should pay himself only at the first time and we should catch money monthly without any user interaction.

So, this scenario is similar to recurring payment but not a typical recurring payment model because the monthly paid amount is **variable** depending on multiple internal factors.

I guess my need can be solved by using "Future payment" but I don't have a mobile app so no mobile SDK.

If future payment is still the best match for me, I tried to obtain oAuth2 token but not sure how can I get authorization code to send it to this API

https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/blob/master/docs/future_payments_server.md#exchange-authorization-code-for-refresh--access-tokens

When I tried to send the ordinary paypal express token, it didn't work so not sure if this authorization token is something different or how can I generate it.

Can anyone advise how can I get user authorization code?

Comment: You should add some code which shows what you have actually attempted.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @max: There is nothing to attempt. The documentation and libraries simply refer to the mobile SDKs, assuming that you're making a mobile app. That's the entire problem.

Comment: I have the same problem.

Comment: same problem here!

Comment: same with my project)

Comment: I found this but can't understand is this the same but for web
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/ht_ap-basicPreapproval-curl-etc/